# How to access Firebase Firestore data when login in using Firebase Auth?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

On an application I'm building, I need to access the stored documents on Firestore after someone logs in using Auth. I have stored data on Firestore when someone creates an account: name, phone, email. I want to access this information when they log back in somewhere else. Is there a way to link the two on account creation or is there some other way to access the documents?

After looking around on the internet for a while, I haven't found any questions related to this, other than trying to login using Firestore, but it had no answers.

Account creation code:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: pass.text!) { (user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFinishCreation", sender: self)
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Storing data on Firestore:

```
FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").document(username).setData([
        "name": username,
        "phone": userphone,
        "email": useremail], completion: { (err) in
            if let err = err {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                print("Document added!")
            }
        }
    )
```

(Btw I used a struct on another swift file using vars called FirebaseFirestore and root)

Login code:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: loginEmail.text!, password: loginPassword.text!) { (user, error) in
        if user != nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toHome", sender: self)
        } else {

        }
    }
```

To summarize, how do I access the data that I stored on account login?

Can anyone help me with this? Anything is appreciated!

Comment: *"I need to access the stored documents on Firestore after someone logs in using Auth"* - which documents exactly?  What's the problem here?

Comment: @DougStevenson, I have stored data on Firestore when someone creates an account: name, phone, email. I want to access this information when they log back in somewhere else.

Comment: This is still pretty unclear.  Please edit the question to how what code have you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  If there is an error message, please share it.

Comment: @DougStevenson, I haven't tried anything yet, since I don't know where to start. I have edited and put in the code of what I have currently.

Comment: Looks like you've already started.  What part exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: @DougStevenson, when the user creates an account, the extra information (name, email, phone) is stored in Firestore. What I am stuck on is that I need to access this data when they log in using Auth from another place. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to query for that document.  Read the documentation to understand how to do that.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: @DougStevenson, the thing is, how will it know which document to grab when the user signs in? There would be multiple accounts and multiple documents, so how does it know that this specific user is linked to another specific document?

Comment: You wrote the document with `FirebaseFirestore.root.collection("users").document(username)`. You would read it with the same path.

Comment: @DougStevenson, oh, it just clicked. Using what you said, I can retrieve using loginEmail.text... I think I got it, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a document of the logged-in user you required document id which is unique. So, add user id as a document id. You will get user id in response while logged in and sign up and then, you can use that id to fetch logged in the user's document.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are saying to set the user id as the document id? How would I do this?

Comment: This link is just about adding data into the Firestore database. But thanks for helping anyways, I figured it out.

Comment: This link is just about adding data into the Firestore database -> it shows how to add custom document id.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a user, create a new Auth in FirebaseAuth as well as the Firestore. Once the user is logged in with the email address, find the user with that email. Although I have not used firestore before, note that this code is done with firebase database instead but the same should apply:

```
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user: User?, error) in

        if error == nil {
            print("You have successfully signed up")

            guard let uid = user?.uid else {
                return
            }

            //successfully authenticated user




            let values = ["name": name, "email": email, "isShop" : shopAccount]
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            let usersReference = ref.child("users").child(uid)
            usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

                ref.child("Orders").child("Total Orders").setValue(0)




                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainPageViewController")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
```

This will then create a user in the FirebaseAuth, and add a new user to the Users section of the database under the uid that is assigned when the account is created. Then you can access this later when the user logs back in as you can retrieve the uid, and find the part of the database containing the information using this code:

```
 dataRef.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
```

As a result, this can be applied to firestore by adding a new document and title to each user added to your FirebaseAuth in order to retrieve future information